# React form data to Java Servlet

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, servlets, crud

I want a solution for my problem. I am facing a problem where the data received from Search.js form is not sending data to my Java Servlet in DYNAMIC WEB PROJECT in Eclipse. I have attached the screenshots and the codes also. Please help.

Search.js Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios  from 'axios';
const  Search = () => {
    
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        if(e.target.value==='' || re.test(e.target.value))
        {
            e.preventDefault()
            let res= fetch("http://localhost:8080/Hrc/search",{
            mode:"no-cors",
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                cust_number:e.target.value
            })})
            console.log(e.target.value)
            if(res.ok)
            {
                console.log("Successful search")
            }
            else{
                console.log("Error")
            }
        }
        // ... submit to API or something
    }
}

    return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit='http://localhost:8080/Hrc/search' method="post">
            <input type="text" name='cust_number' placeholder='Search Customer Id' className="sarch-button" onKeyPress={handleSubmit}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

App.js

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import {useMemo}  from 'react'
import Logo from './components/Logo.js'
import './App.css'
import PredictBtn from './components/PredictBtn.js'
import Analytics from './components/AnalyticsView.js'
import Advsrchmodal from './components/Advsrchmodal.js'
import Search from './components/Search.js'
import Add from './components/Addmodal.js'
import Edit from './components/Edit.js'
import Delete from './components/Delete.js'
import Table from './components/Table.js'
import table from './assets/json/mock.json'
import {Columns} from './components/column'
export default function App(){
  const [advmodal,setadvmodal]=useState(false)
  const [addmodal,setaddmodal]=useState(false)
  const [editmodal,seteditmodal]=useState(false)
  const [delmodal,setdelmodal]=useState(false)
  const [search,setSearch]=useState('')
  const searchItems=(searchValue)=>{
    setSearch(searchValue)
  }
  const columns = useMemo(()=> Columns ,[])
  const data = useMemo(()=> table, [])
    return(
    <div>
      <body>
      <Logo />
      <div className='header-btns'>
        <PredictBtn/><Analytics/>
        <button onClick={()=> setadvmodal(true)} className="leftbtns adv-srch-btn"id="adv-srch-modal">ADVANCED SEARCH</button>
        <Advsrchmodal onClose={()=> setadvmodal(false)} show={advmodal}/>
        
        
        <Search handleSearch={searchItems}/>
      
        <button onClick={()=> setaddmodal(true)} className="rightbtns add-btn" id ="add-modal">ADD</button>
        <Add onClose={()=> setaddmodal(false)} show={addmodal}/>
      
      
        <button onClick={()=> seteditmodal(true)} className="rightbtns edit-btn">EDIT</button>
        <Edit onClose={()=> seteditmodal(false)} show={editmodal}/>

        <button onClick={()=> setdelmodal(true)} className="rightbtns del-btn">DELETE</button>
        <Delete onClose={()=>setdelmodal(false)} show={delmodal}/>
      </div>
      <div className="Table">
        <Table columns={Columns} data={data}/>
      </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Ignore the other imports , focus on the search import

Search.java('The Servlet') code:

```
package com.highradius;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.io.FileWriter;

@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class Search extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grey_goose?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
    
    static final String USER="root";
    static final String PASSWORD="ROHITghosh1234";
    
    

    public Search() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:3000");
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        List<Response> demoList = new ArrayList<>();
        String cust_number=req.getParameter("cust_number");
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            if(cust_number=="")
                sql="select sl_no,business_code,cust_number,clear_date,buisness_year,doc_id,posting_date,document_create_date,due_in_date,invoice_currency,document_type,posting_id,total_open_amount,baseline_create_date,cust_payment_terms,invoice_id from winter_internship";
            else
                sql="select sl_no,business_code,cust_number,clear_date,buisness_year,doc_id,posting_date,document_create_date,due_in_date,invoice_currency,document_type,posting_id,total_open_amount,baseline_create_date,cust_payment_terms,invoice_id from winter_internship where cust_number like '"+cust_number+"%'";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                Response res=new Response();
                res.setsl_no(rs.getInt("sl_no"));
                res.setbusiness_code(rs.getString("business_code"));
                res.setcust_number(rs.getString("cust_number"));
                res.setclear_date(rs.getDate("clear_date"));
                res.setbuisness_year(rs.getInt("buisness_year"));
                res.setdoc_id(rs.getString("doc_id"));
                res.setposting_date(rs.getDate("posting_date"));
                res.setdocument_create_date(rs.getDate("document_create_date"));
                res.setdue_in_date(rs.getDate("due_in_date"));
                res.setinvoice_currency(rs.getString("invoice_currency"));
                res.setdocument_type(rs.getString("document_type"));
                res.setposting_id(rs.getInt("posting_id"));
                res.settotal_open_amount(rs.getDouble("total_open_amount"));
                res.setbaseline_create_date(rs.getDate("baseline_create_date"));
                res.setcust_payment_terms(rs.getString("cust_payment_terms"));
                res.setinvoice_id(rs.getInt("invoice_id"));
                demoList.add(res);
            }
                String jsonString = getJSONStringFromObject(demoList);
                resp.setContentType("application/json");
                try {
                    resp.getWriter().write(jsonString);
                    File files=new File("D:\\\\hrcsummerinternship\\\\src\\\\assets\\\\json\\\\searchoutput.json");
                    files.delete();
                    FileWriter file=new FileWriter("D:\\hrcsummerinternship\\src\\assets\\json\\searchoutput.json");
                    
                    file.write(jsonString);
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conn != null)
                        conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
    private String getJSONStringFromObject(List<Response> filmlist) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(filmlist);
        //System.out.print(json);
        return json;
    }

}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqCYb.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrKbo.png)

I have also used axios, but to no avail. Please Help

Comment: Any help fellow coders?